# How to avoid Nokogiri encoding href content?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have this code:

```
n = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<a href='{{var_name}}'>click</a>")
```

and when I do `n.to_html`, I get the `{{ }}` escaped:

```
"<a href=\"%7B%7Bvar_name%7D%7D\">click</a>"
```

I want to avoid that, because I need to parse it with a template engine.

How can I tell Nokogiri not to encode the "href" content?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to tell Nokogiri to *not* encode text values inside parameters in HTML. It's a parser following rules, but that doesn't mean we have to accept its output:

```
require 'nokogiri'

REGEX_HASH = {
  '%7B' => '{',
  '%7D' => '}'
}

REGEX = /(?:#{ Regexp.union(REGEX_HASH.keys).source })/
# => /(?:%7B|%7D)/

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<a href='{{var_name}}'>click</a>")
doc.to_html
# => "<a href=\"%7B%7Bvar_name%7D%7D\">click</a>"

fixed_html = doc.to_html.gsub(REGEX, REGEX_HASH)
# => "<a href=\"{{var_name}}\">click</a>"
```

But, if XHTML or XML output is acceptable, you can simplify things greatly:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<a href='{{var_name}}'>click</a>")
doc.to_html  # => "<a href=\"%7B%7Bvar_name%7D%7D\">click</a>"
doc.to_xhtml # => "<a href=\"{{var_name}}\">click</a>"
doc.to_xml   # => "<a href=\"{{var_name}}\">click</a>"
```